# Binding number and operator buttons to calculator buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I really have no idea how to do button binding since I have never tried it before but I do have a code for button binding that works my problem is that, I can't incorporate the working button binding code into my calculator code which uses a class. What do I have to do to make this work?

here is the code for button binding that I have:

```
from functools import partial
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def key(event):
    print ("pressed", repr(event.char))
    if event.char.isdigit():
        append_digit(event.char)
    elif event.char in ('\x08', '\x7f'):
        backspace()

def callback(event):
    frame.focus_set()
    print ("clicked at", event.x, event.y)

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<Key>", key)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
frame.pack()

current = IntVar(0)
label = Label(frame, textvariable=current)
label.pack()

def button_callback(i):
    print ("clicked button {}".format(i))
    append_digit(i)

def append_digit(digit):
    current.set(current.get() * 10 + int(digit))

def backspace():
    current.set(current.get() // 10)

for i in '1234567890':
    Button(frame, text=i, command=partial(button_callback, i)).pack()
Button(frame, text='C', command=backspace).pack()

frame.focus_set()
root.mainloop()
```

here is my actual calculator code:

```
        numbers=["7", "4", "1", "8", "5", "2", "9", "6", "3"]
        for i in range(9):
            n=numbers[i]
            Button(buttons, bg="snow", text=n, width=7, height=1, command=show_up(n), relief=RAISED).grid(row=i%3, column=i//3)
 Clear = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text="C", width=7, height=1, command=self.clear, relief=RAISED)
        Clear.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=3, row=0)
        Equals = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text="=", width=7, height=1, command=self.equals, relief=RAISED)
        Equals.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=4, row=3)
        All_clear = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text="AC", width=7, height=1, command=self.all_clear, relief=RAISED)
        All_clear.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=4, row=0)
        Bracket_one = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text="(", width=7, height=1, command=self.bracket_one, relief=RAISED)
        Bracket_one.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=2, row=3)
        Bracket_two = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text=")", width=7, height=1, command=self.bracket_two, relief=RAISED)
        Bracket_two.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=3, row=3)
        Zero = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text="0", width=7, height=1, command=self.zero, relief=RAISED)
        Zero.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=0, row=3)
        Decimal_point = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text=".", width=7, height=1, command=self.decimal_point, relief=RAISED)
        Decimal_point.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=1, row=3)
        Multiplication = Button(buttons, bg="red", text="x", width=7, height=1, command=self.multiplication, relief=RAISED)
        Multiplication.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=3, row=1)
        Division = Button(buttons, bg="powder blue", text="/", width=7, height=1, command=self.division, relief=RAISED)
        Division.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=4, row=1)
        Addition = Button(buttons, bg="yellow", text="+", width=7, height=1, command=self.addition, relief=RAISED)
        Addition.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=3, row=2)
        Subtraction = Button(buttons, bg="green", text="-", width=7, height=1, command=self.subtraction, relief=RAISED)
        Subtraction.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=4, row=2)

    def equals(self):
        try:
            result = eval(self.results.get())
        except:
            result = "Error"
        self.all_clear()
        self.results.insert(0, result)
    def zero(self):
        self.results.insert(END, "0")
    def bracket_one(self):
        self.results.insert(END, "(")
    def bracket_two(self):
        self.results.insert(END, ")")
    def all_clear(self):
        self.results.delete(0, END)
    def clear(self):
        self.results.delete(-1)
    def multiplication(self):
        self.results.insert(END, "*")
    def division(self):
        self.results.insert(END, "/")
    def addition(self):
        self.results.insert(END, "+")
    def subtraction(self):
        self.results.insert(END, "-")
    def decimal_point(self):
        self.results.insert(END, ".")
```

Comment: Are you talking about binding the `number` buttons?

Comment: yes as well as the operator buttons

Comment: The operator buttons seem to be correctly bound

Comment: do they? how come when I press minus on my keyboard the calculator won't show up with a "-" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You button bindings (to callbacks) are all correct.

The issue is with your `self.results` entry -

```
self.results = Entry(display, textvariable=numbers, width=31, fg="snow", bg="snow", font="Verdana")
```

You have set the font color as well as the background color to same color, so even though the numbers do show up in your calculator , they are not visible. Change the font color (fg) to something else, like black or so -

```
self.results = Entry(display, textvariable=numbers, width=31, fg="black", bg="snow", font="Verdana")
```

---

For the actual required , which was not clear in the question , that is to bind keyboard keys . The main portion of the button/operator binding script you put that does that is -

```
frame.bind("<Key>", key)
```

And

```
def key(event):
    print ("pressed", repr(event.char))
    if event.char.isdigit():
        append_digit(event.char)
    elif event.char in ('\x08', '\x7f'):
        backspace()
```

You can simply add them to your class as (Along with some other small changes for improvement) -

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
from tkinter import messagebox
root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
root.geometry("317x145")

menubar = Menu(root)

class Calculator(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        master.bind("<Key>", self.key)
        display = Frame(root, bd=0, width=1000, height=1000, relief=SUNKEN)
        buttons = Frame(root, bd=0, width=7, height=1, relief=GROOVE)
        display.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=0, pady=0)
        buttons.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=1)
        numbers = StringVar()
        self.results = Entry(display, textvariable=numbers, width=31, fg="black", bg="snow", font="Verdana")
        self.results.pack()
        self.results.grid(column=0, row=0)

        numbers=["7", "4", "1", "8", "5", "2", "9", "6", "3"]
        for i in range(9):
            n=numbers[i]
            Button(buttons, bg="snow", text=n, width=7, height=1, command=self.show_up(n), relief=RAISED).grid(row=i%3, column=i//3)
        Clear = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text="C", width=7, height=1, command=self.clear, relief=RAISED)
        Clear.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=3, row=0)
        Equals = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text="=", width=7, height=1, command=self.equals, relief=RAISED)
        Equals.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=4, row=3)
        All_clear = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text="AC", width=7, height=1, command=self.all_clear, relief=RAISED)
        All_clear.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=4, row=0)
        Bracket_one = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text="(", width=7, height=1, command=self.bracket_one, relief=RAISED)
        Bracket_one.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=2, row=3)
        Bracket_two = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text=")", width=7, height=1, command=self.bracket_two, relief=RAISED)
        Bracket_two.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=3, row=3)
        Zero = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text="0", width=7, height=1, command=self.zero, relief=RAISED)
        Zero.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=0, row=3)
        Decimal_point = Button(buttons, bg="snow", text=".", width=7, height=1, command=self.decimal_point, relief=RAISED)
        Decimal_point.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=1, row=3)
        Multiplication = Button(buttons, bg="red", text="x", width=7, height=1, command=self.multiplication, relief=RAISED)
        Multiplication.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=3, row=1)
        Division = Button(buttons, bg="powder blue", text="/", width=7, height=1, command=self.division, relief=RAISED)
        Division.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=4, row=1)
        Addition = Button(buttons, bg="yellow", text="+", width=7, height=1, command=self.addition, relief=RAISED)
        Addition.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=3, row=2)
        Subtraction = Button(buttons, bg="green", text="-", width=7, height=1, command=self.subtraction, relief=RAISED)
        Subtraction.grid(padx=2, pady=2, column=4, row=2)

    def key(self, event):
        if event.char.isdigit():
            self.results.insert(END, event.char)
        elif event.char in ('\x08', '\x7f'):
            self.clear()

    def show_up(self, x):
        return lambda: self.results.insert(END, x)

    def equals(self):
        try:
            result = eval(self.results.get())
        except:
            result = "Error"
        self.all_clear()
        self.results.insert(0, result)
    def zero(self):
        self.results.insert(END, "0")
    def bracket_one(self):
        self.results.insert(END, "(")
    def bracket_two(self):
        self.results.insert(END, ")")
    def all_clear(self):
        self.results.delete(0, END)
    def clear(self):
        self.results.delete(len(self.results.get()) - 1)
    def multiplication(self):
        self.results.insert(END, "*")
    def division(self):
        self.results.insert(END, "/")
    def addition(self):
        self.results.insert(END, "+")
    def subtraction(self):
        self.results.insert(END, "-")
    def decimal_point(self):
        self.results.insert(END, ".")    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Calculator(root)
    root.config(menu=menubar)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ohhhhhh  I see I can see them now :) But I meant button binding as in when I press for example, the number 5, I wouldn't have to click on the calculator display screen then press the number 5 in order to see "5" on the display. Do I make sense...?

Comment: You mean keyboard keys?

Comment: Oh thank you so much I just have one question ... everything works but when I press backspace it adds it on to the list of pressed buttons instead of deleting entries..How can I make it so that the backspace deletes entries?

Comment: make changes as in your binding script , instead of backspace function call in other script, call `self.clear()` .

Comment: sorry .. but I don't get how to do what you are saying although I do see that it'll work. How exactly do I call in `self.clear()` ?

Comment: Glad I could be helpful.

Comment: I just got an AttributeError: `NoneType` object has no attribute `bind` how do I fix this? :(

Comment: it showed up because of line 19 where the `master.bind` is . I think its because I added my message box code in .. but I really don't know what happened

Comment: Maybe you should ask a new question with the latest code , and your addition